# Page content not centered, css, jquery

Tags: jquery, css, web, visual-web-developer, word-wrap

I'm working on a page and for some reason I struggle to center everything within the page:
I've already used everything mentioned on the web.

I'm quit new to css, so any help would be appreciated:

**here's the HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Codrops top bar -->           

       <section class="rw-wrapper"><h2 width: 100%;">
       <div style="text-align: center;" id="me"><img src="images/me.png" alt="me"></div>

        <div style="float: left; text-align: center;">This is X,&nbsp;</div>
            <div style=" float: left; text-align: center;" class="rw-words rw-words-1"> <span>Hello</span> <span>Hi</span> <span>Hola</span> <span>Bonjour</span> <span>Ciao</span> <span>Salam</span> </div><br>
            <br>

        </h2>
```

```
        <div style="text-align: center;">

        <blockquote>
        <p>
```

1

```
        </h2>
```

For some reason I couldnt post the css...

Comment: "I've already used everything mentioned on the web." I _highly_ doubt that.

Comment: Also your opening H2 markup is invalid: `<h2 width: 100%;">`

Comment: Remove your styling from the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You have CSS in your HTML so I would take that out and put it with the rest of your CSS. To solve as is though you need to give whatever you need to center a width and then use margin:0 auto; eg:

```
     <div id="wrapper" style="width:50%; margin:0 auto;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center a `div` using `margin: 0 auto;`. You cannot do that if you use `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to center the text or the containers?

Centering a container is usually fairly easy:

```
div#wrapper {
  margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Im trying to center the containers and also the text within the containers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to externalize your styling from within your HTML, which will make things much clearer. You also have some invalid markup in that of which you have posted.

Google a basic CSS tutorial if need be, or head to [W3Fools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/).

However From a quick glance, you need to use:

`magin: 0 auto` on your `wrapper` div. The 0 covers the margin for both the bottom and top margin and the auto, well I hope you can guess, will automatically provide an even margin either side of your div. Therfore centering your div.

see my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/FY7UR/) I have made some changes to your HTML which I assumed are not necessary and were merely attempts of yours to get the result you desire: